# Julia 1.0.0: Error trying to add PyPlot package

Tags: julia

Not sure how to respond to the following error message trying to add PyPlot:

```
julia> # Fresh 1.0.0 REPL

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.0.0
Commit 5d4eaca0c9 (2018-08-08 20:58 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.0 (ORCJIT, haswell)

(v1.0) pkg> add PyPlot
  Updating registry at `C:\Users\Jim\.julia\registries\General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Benchmark [de6e09b3]:
 Benchmark [de6e09b3] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.0.1-0.0.3, 0.1.0] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.0.1-0.0.3, 0.1.0]
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Based on Bogumił Kamiński's very helpful answer, I did the following and it worked, after restarting the REPL.  This is a short summary, based on responding to error messages:

```
(v1.0) pkg> rm Benchmark

(v1.0) pkg> add PyPlot

(v1.0) pkg> build PyCall

# Restart REPL
julia> using PyPlot

julia> plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 5, 10, 4, 2])
1-element Array{PyCall.PyObject,1}:
 PyObject <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000034CDEE48>

julia> # It works!
```

[image: PyPlot Image]

Comment: Nice update :).

Comment: Thanks, and thanks again for your help.  I was stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://discourse.julialang.org/t/package-compatibility-caps/15301.

Most likely the problem is that you have installed package `Benchmark` which is not maintained.

Uninstall package `Benchmark` by: `(v1.0) pkg> rm Benchmark` before trying to install `PyPlot`.

Comment: Does that mean I can't use both Benchmark and PyPlot?  Maybe I should go with GadFly?  New to Julia and not sure which way to go for graphics.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for your timely answer!

Comment: This means that you can't use `Benchmark` package. `PyPlot` does not depend on it so you can safely remove it. I recommend you to use `BenchmarkTools` instead of `Benchmark` (I guess you have even made a Q-A entry on StackOverflow about it recently).

Comment: Ok, I see now that Benchmark and BenchmarkTools are two different packages.  Somehow that, probably obvious, difference escaped me in looking at the error message.  Thanks again!

Comment: Actually BenchmarkTools replaced Benchmark some time ago, so it is easy to miss it.