# GLText Package in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia

When I try to install various packages in Julia 1.0 I get an error regarding the GLText package:

```
(v1.0) pkg> add Makie
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package GLText [02a96ca5]:
 GLText [02a96ca5] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.0.1-0.0.4 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with GLPlot [9bedddac] to versions: 

0.0.1-0.0.4
     │ └─GLPlot [9bedddac] log:
     │   ├─possible versions are: 0.0.2-0.0.5 or uninstalled
     │   └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.0.2-0.0.5
     └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

I am working on macOS Sierra

Answer (score 2):

This error message indicates that there are no available versions of the package which have been certified by the package author as compatible with Julia 0.7 (or 1.0). GLText and its successor GLVisualize are not currently installable with the latest Julia. It might be necessary to install Julia 0.6 if you must use that package.

Comment: The question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485573/julia-1-0-0-error-trying-to-add-pyplot-package.

Comment: So, in JuliaObserver one of the most installed packages is Makie and there are even explicit instructions for installing it in Julia 1.0.  I try to install it in Julia 1.0 on Mac OS and I still get this GLText error.  So now my question is, how can Makie be installed on Julia 1.0 if there is a dependency on GLText which is not compatible with Julia 1.0?

Comment: I will add that I come from R where there are certainly package dependencies but they are not as insidious as the ones I am encountering in Julia which is littered with packages which are a) no longer maintained and/or b) incompatible with later versions of Julia.  My broad comment as a software developer for approximately 40 years is that Julia is wander into obscurity unless it a) establishes a robust set of packages and b) has a environment which is simple to maintain for the use.